# Move word by word in Unix command line

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

I work on `tcsh` and would like to navigate word forwards, backwards in Unix command line.

Google search shows <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> for moving forward by one word and moving backward by one word. But it doesn't work on Unix command line. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `bindkey` to list keybinds:

```
[~]% bindkey | grep -E '(forward|backward)-word'

"^[B"          -> backward-word
"^[F"          -> forward-word
"^[b"          -> backward-word
"^[f"          -> forward-word
```

`^[` is the escape character, so this is <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd>. Some terminal emulators may also send <kbd>Alt</kbd> as the escape character (but yours obviously doesn't).

Your settings may be different, but this seems to be the default, on my Linux & FreeBSD systems.

To set this to, for example, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, you can use:

```
 bindkey '^f' forward-word
```

Or for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>:

```
bindkey 'M-f' forward-word
```

Add this to your `~/.tcshrc` to make it permanent.

See the [manpage entry on `bindkey`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#bindkey) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does M- represent Atl and ^ represent Ctrl?

Comment: @Raghav Yes, see the manpage I linked (at the `-b`  entry, which seems to be the default, and it probably there for backward compatibility).